# MySQL Inner Join Query Only Returning DISTINCT VALUES

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following query is intended for a pagination script that is to return news posts from a DB. It works, but does not return any items with same dates, or title.

How do I rewrite this in order to get items with same title and/or same date?

Query:

```
"SELECT p.post_id, p.post_title, p.post_detail, p.post_user, p.post_slug, p.post_date, p.post_type 
 FROM ".TBL_POSTS." as p 
 LEFT JOIN ".TBL_POST_CATEGORIES." as c
 ON c.post_ID = p.post_id
 WHERE p.post_type = 'post' AND c.category_ID = 5
 GROUP BY p.post_date DESC", 10);
```

Here is an example of the POST table

```
--------------------------------------------
post_id | post_title  | post_date
--------------------------------------------
10      | news post 1 | 2014-02-13 21:09:45
--------------------------------------------
12      | news post 2 | 2014-02-14 21:09:45
--------------------------------------------
```

Here is an example of the CATEGORIES table

```
--------------------------------------------
id      | post_ID  | category_ID
--------------------------------------------
1       | 10       | 5
--------------------------------------------
2       | 12       | 5
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Make sure that your columns in where clause has correct data, i.e. remove where clause and then try to execute.

Comment: @AK47  the issue was with the (GROUP BY) I should've used (ORDER BY). Thank you.

Comment: @CosmoGroup by is not required at all, you are correct. but that is not correct reason for wrong output.Even though date col. is in group by but it will grouped by full date including hh:mm:sss, record which has difference in seconds will be also treated sepretly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the GROUP BY usage.

SQL only returns one record *per distinct grouped column values* - every other column, not in the group by clause, *should* be in an aggregate function.

Unfortunately, MySQL silently accepts this incorrect query (which has been the source of many bugs) and selects a record ["at random"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4767762/2864740) from the grouping. In this case, since only post_date is in the grouping, there will be only one record per unique date/time.

---

I suspect *a* "correct" behavior is simply to remove the GROUP BY (perhaps replacing it with ORDER BY), although this might not be the intent - updating the post with *expected* output could lead to useful suggestions on how to update the query.

Comment: even though date col. is in group by but it will grouped by full date including hh:mm:sss, record which has difference in seconds will be also treated sepretly.

Comment: @user2864740 How else would I get this query to sort by descending date or ascending date without the group by?

Comment: @Cosmo Just sort on (ORDER BY) the field; what is with the grouping? (Without a hierarchical format like XML, which is provided by some vendors, SQL can *only* return tabular data and GROUP BY still results in tabular output.)

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you that solved it. Not sure I understand your question "what is with the grouping?". The grouping is pull events from oldest to newest with the option of doing vice versa. I hope I understood your question.

Comment: @Cosmo I meant, "Why do the results need to be grouped?" I am glad you were able to solve your problem.

Comment: @user2864740 The posts table stores items that are in separate categories. i.e. cat_5 is news, cat_4 is random, etc. news.php pulls data from cat_5, random.php pulls from cat_4, and so on. Does this make sense?